# How to get the owner of file using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am thinking of developing an application like this:

1. My application has a google-service-account
2. I let my users share their documents with my service account
3. While an user visits my application, he gets some reports based on the files he has shared.

For this, my application needs to uniquely identify the owner of the documents shared with it. I looked at the API but could not find how to do so. I found methods like [File.getOwnerNames()](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/drive/v2/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html), but they are plain strings containing the names, but not any unique key to identify the user.

Need help on how to achieve this. Thanks.

Sanjay

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [permissions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list) method and find the permission corresponding to the owner.

Comment: Using permission.list, I got a permission object with role=owner, name=Sanjay Patel (user who is the owner of the application) and id=somenumber which is not the profile_id of that user. I am unable to know what id is that, and how to get an unique id of the owner.

Comment: You can check that ID against the ID returned in the about collection. You should know who the current user is.

Comment: Sorry I could not get. Is there an ID present in the about collection of users?

Comment: Yes, look at the permissionID field in https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about#resource

Comment: Can you get the file owner's email address this way?

Comment: this doesn't work. at least not for the case where some other user has shared a file with the current user and the current user requests a list of files available. the shared file will be listed and the other user's name will be listed, but the other user's id is not available. the "about" api is only for current user. the other user's name is meaningless because it is not a unique id. correct me if i am wrong.